# IE BHO Tab key focus issue

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, key, accessibility, bho

We are currently implementing a browser helper object (BHO) for internet explorer. The BHO is embedded in a HTML using OBJECT tag. We are facing a keyboard accessibility problem with it. The use case is as below:

1. User can move the focus from BHO to IE chrome (address bar to be specific) using ALT+D.
2. Now, we are expecting that with continuous tabbing from IE chrome, user should ultimately end up having focus in BHO.
3. However, the focus is not shifting in BHO.
4. It remains twice on the last component in IE chrome and then circles back to address bar.

We have tried having tabindex attribute set on the OBJECT tag. However, no luck.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Vikas K.

Comment: Vikas, I am trying to understand your issue. Essentially your BHO is acting like it isn't there as far as keyboard accessibility is concerned. You also posted: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ac13fcd6-5850-4a77-a1c8-e573d27e4acf

Answer (score 0):

BHOs are not embedded via OBJECT.  ActiveX controls are.  Your BHO and your ActiveX control **should not be the same object**.  They have different sites and you will need to implement `IObjectWithSite`.  Now what?

Anyway, my psychic powers tell me you forgot to implement `IInputObject`.